# Как разбитый столбец разбить еще раз sql?

Tags: sql

Раделил столбец с помощью split_part. Нужно в том же запросе разделить полученные столбцы еще раз. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Столбец панель разделить на два по #.

```
select
split_part(id,'_',1) as визит,
split_part(id,'_',2) as продукт,
split_part(id,'_',3) as панель,
split_part(id,'_',4) as стенд,
split_part(id,'_',5) as магазин
from vizit_products_rtt vpr
```

Comment: Ну используй два SPLIT_PART, один внутри другого... или первый разбор в CTE, второй во внешнем запросе.

Comment: неправильно у вас организовано хранение информации, раз вам приходится извлекать явно ключевую информацию из строки.